# Es posible Castear objetos de clases abstractas

Tags: java, java-swing, polimorfismo

hola que tal tengo una duda que me esta matando espero que me puedan ayudar

### lo que sé según lo que yo tengo entendido:

> no se pueden instanciar objetos de una clase abstracta

### mi duda:

la clase Graphics2D hereda de Graphics ambos son abstractas osea no puedo instanciar objetos directamente de ambas. entonces eh creado una clase GraFi que extiende o hereda de Graphics y luego quiero castearlo a Graphics2D pero tengo un error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

error:

```
Cannot cast from GraFi to Graphics2D
```

yo pensé que quizás sea por que no se puede transformar a Graphics2D por el nivel de la herencia(quizás estoy equivocado).

### ahora bien cuando hago esto las cosas cambian pero quisiera saber por que:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como veran allí desaparece el error pero ahi me surge la duda si antes al crear un objeto de la clase GraFi que heredaba de Graphics no me dejaba convertirla a Graphics2D por que ahora que instancio un objeto de Grafi a graficosDeGraphics perteneciente a Graphics ya no me da error si en ambos casos se esta tratando de convertir de graphics a Graphics2D aun cuando en el primer caso cree así

```
Grafi graficoDeGraphics = new Grafi();
```

si GraFi a pertenecido a GraFi

Comment: Esto tiene más que ver con los upcasting y downcasting, que con las clases abstractas. Las 2 clases serían dos clases derivadas de Graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que ya te has respondido tú sólo, pero te lo pongo de un modo más formal.

Lo mismo lo ves más claro con el clásico ejemplo *zoológico*

```
abstract class Animal {...}
abstract class Mamifero extends Animal {...}
abstract class Ave extends Animal {...}
class Aguila extends Ave {...}
```

Como es de esperar:

```
Aguila a= new Aguila()
if (a instanceof Ave) {
   ... //entra
}
if (a instanceof Animal) {
   ... //entra porque un Aguila es un Ave, que es un Animal
   Animal an = a; //no hace falta ni hacer casting, es implícito por ser seguro
}
if (a instanceof Mamifero) {
  ... // aqui no va a entrar
}

Animal an = new Aguila() //funciona

Aguila ag= (Aguila) an;
//funciona pero, como restringes, hace falta el casting explícito.
// (decir que es un Aguila es más restrictivo que decir un Animal)
```

La última asignación te ha exigido un casting explícito para obligarte a decirle al compilador *sé lo que estoy haciendo*. Es decir, no todos los animales son águilas pero **sé** que en este caso sí es así y puedo forzarlo.

```
Mamifero m= (Mamifero) a;  //no te deja, en ningún caso un Aguila es un mamifero
```

Answer (score 1):

En el primer ejemplo estas casteando dos clases (hermanas) que hereadan de Graphics entonces, es decir, ambas clases tienen unas propiedades comunes pero no son iguales como para castear, así que esta mal.

El segundo caso te deja por que estas definiendo la clase Grafi como una clase Graphics y te deja castearlo por que Graphics es una clase padre de Graphics2D.

En resumen, las clase abstractas se pueden heredar pero tienes problemas para entender la herencia echale un vistazo. Mi consejo es...

> Siempre castea de hijos a padres y nunca castees de padres a hijos, a no ser que estes muy seguro de que esa clase padre contiene las propiedades necesarias para poder castear correctamente al hijo.